# Autofill HTML form returned blank page

Tags: javascript

I am working on a Wordpress website with Pinpoint booking system plugin. I would like to fill the booking from automatically using javascript. Take [this demo](https://pinpoint.world/demos/wordpress-booking/calendar/) as example. From browser inspect element, the Id for first name is `DOPBSPCalendar-form-field1_1`. So I put this code on address bar to try setting the text.

```
javascript:document.getElementById('DOPBSPCalendar-form-field1_1').value='first';
```

A blank page with the word "first" is displayed. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it's not working is because the form is inside an iframe (`id = calendar-demo`, `class = example-demo-iframe`).  The page won't let you target elements inside the iframe from the address bar.

You can type this line, which will display "IFRAME" and confirm that the iframe is present:

```
javascript:alert(document.getElementById('calendar-demo').tagName);
```

But any attempt to target elements inside the iframe will fail.  For example, trying to run this line:

```
javascript:alert(document.getElementById('calendar-demo').innerHTML);
```

will return a blank popup window.

**UPDATE:**

To answer your edited question, wrap your statement in a function call (or `void()`) to prevent a return value from changing the whole page.

You could do it like this:

```
javascript:(function(){document.getElementById('DOPBSPCalendar-form-field1_1').value='first';})();
```

Or this:

```
javascript:void(document.getElementById('DOPBSPCalendar-form-field1_1').value='first');
```

Comment: Please check by edited question, I tried to open the iframe page, https://pinpoint.world/demos/wordpress-booking/calendar/ and run the javascript, but a blank page is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The browsers cross-origin security policy will not let you access the contents of an iFrame if that is pointing to another domain.

However, there is the [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) method, which can send serialized data to such an iFrame.

```
otherWindow.postMessage('{greetings: "Hello iFrame content"}', '*');
```

Then you can set an event handler in the content running inside the iframe and get this data.

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(data){
    console.log(data);
}, false);
```

Now, the things will become interesting, if you do the same (send a message) from within the iFrame as a reply with the data you are looking for.

Ending up with your own little protocol of data communication between these two windows will open up a lot of possibilities to do pretty much anything you want.

But remember, this is possible only if you have control over the contents that run inside botht the iFrame and the parent window.

Comment: Please check by edited question, I tried to open the iframe page, https://pinpoint.world/demos/wordpress-booking/calendar/ and run the javascript, but a blank page is displayed.